# How does Krew compare to Helm?

Tags: helm

I've use Helm before, but I see some projects now are supporting a new plugin manager called Krew. Specifically, minio, provides a Krew package.

What is the difference between Krew and Helm? How do they compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do different things,

- [Krew](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/) is a **plugin manager for `kubectl`** the client-side cli tools for Kubernetes. For example, minio uses Krew becuase it provides `kubectl minio` which is the [MinIO Kubernetes plugin](https://min.io/docs/minio/kubernetes/upstream/reference/kubectl-minio-plugin.html).
- [Helm](https://helm.sh/) is a **package manager for Kubernetes**. This is allows you to install software (mostly through [Kubernetes operators](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/)) onto your cluster.